# When is CWebUser->afterLogin() called for cookie logins in Yii?

Tags: yii

I'm using Yii v1.1.14. I extended `CWebUser` with a custom `WebUser` class and overrided the `afterLogin` function. This takes a `$fromCookie` parameter, which works great for adding special logic for cookie-based logins, since those bypass the `SiteController` login action. However, this doesn't seem to be called until after I reference `Yii::app()->user` in my own code. I would have thought that this event would be raised automatically. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from the Yii Framework Forum from user Joblo:

The method `afterLogin()` is called by `CWebUser::restoreFromCookie` in `CWebUser::init()`.
So you do have to reference Yii::app()->user.